# Convex hull decomposition

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

I recently encountered the following problem:
Given (d+2) points $x_1, ..., x_{d+2}$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$. 
Is it true that 
conv($x_1, ..., x_{d+2}$) = $\bigcup_{i=1}^{d+2}$ conv($x_1, ..., \hat{x_i}, ..., x_{d+2}$), 
where the symbol $\hat{}$ means omission ?

I cannot find a counterexample and also cannot prove it. I tried to prove the RHS is convex but cannot proceed after writing down the formula of convex hull.

Any counterexample, proof, or any helpful theorem is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's the content of [Carathéodory's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(convex_hull)).

> If $S \subseteq \mathbb R^d$ and $x \in \operatorname{conv}(S)$, then there are $x_1, \dots, x_{d+1} \in S$ such that $x \in \operatorname{conv}(x_1, \dots, x_{d+1})$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly the theorem I need. LOL